# Set voice over focus on UITextView

Tags: ios, iphone, accessibility, voiceover

How can I set voice over focus on my element (such like `UITextView`) in iOS 6. Is it possible?

Comment: http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2010/09/openears-speech-library-for-iphone-using-cmusphinx/

Answer (score 1):

Very simple. Just do this:

```
UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification, textView);
```

Note that it may not work, depending on where and when you use it. If you're trying to set the focus to a particular element from `viewDidLoad`, the code probably won't work correctly. This is because VoiceOver makes its own attempt to set the VoiceOver focus on an element initially; if VoiceOver does this before it processes your attempt to set focus, your code will work. But if VoiceOver gets around to setting the initial focused element after it processes your attempt, your code will appear to fail.

A somewhat more reliable way to do this in `viewDidLoad` is to use `performSelector:withObject:withDelay:`, to ensure that your call is processed after VoiceOver's initial focus setting.