# JQuery Mobile force VoiceOver to focus on title after GotoPage

Tags: jquery, iphone, jquery-mobile, voiceover

With `JQuery mobile` and `VoiceOver` active,  after changing page with

```
$.mobile.changePage("page1.html");
```

`VoiceOver` don't focus on the title.
I want to force the focus of `VoiceOver` to read the title of the new page

**NOT** working tests:

```
$(".ui-page-active .ui-title").click().focus().tap();
$(".ui-page-active .ui-title").trigger("create");
$(".ui-page-active .ui-title").attr("role","alert");
$(".ui-page-active .ui-title").attr("role","dialog");
```

test page, not always working
https://jsfiddle.net/218xLbwd/14/

**SOLUTION : use beforeshow event to focus on title.**
thanks also Eric D. Johnson for his effort

```js
  //for Jquery till  1.4.0
  $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', function() {
    $(".ui-page-active > .ui-header h1").attr('tabindex', "-1");
    $(".ui-page-active > .ui-header h1").focus();
  });
  //for Jquery 1.6.0+
  $(document).on('pagecontainerbeforeshow', function() {
    $(".ui-page-active > .ui-header h1").attr('tabindex', "-1");
    $(".ui-page-active > .ui-header h1").focus();
  });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14401772/set-voice-over-focus-on-uitextview

Comment: not relevant, its not in native code but js/html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE: Using jQuery Mobile**

*Stackoverflow snippet doesn't run, so see https://jsfiddle.net/EricOP/wo40z1m9/3/*

HTML

```
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Foo</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="content">
    <p>I'm first in the source order so I'm shown as the first page.</p>
    <p>View internal page called <a id="barclick" href="#bar">bar</a></p>
  </div>

  <div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Page Footer</h4>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- Start of second page -->
<div data-role="page" id="bar">

  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Bar</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="content">
    <p>I'm the second in the source order so I'm hidden when the page loads. I'm just shown if a link that references my id is beeing clicked.</p>
    <p><a href="#foo">Back to foo</a></p>
  </div>

  <div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Page Footer</h4>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
/* CSS to prevent weird blue border in Chrome after setting focus */ 
h2:focus { outline: 0; }
```

JS

```
(function() {
  // For changing to a specific page. 
  // Also see https://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#event-beforeshow which was helpful for Sano.
  $("#bar").on('pageshow', function(barPage) {
    console.warn('Pageshow on bar, Sano.', barPage);
    $("h1:visible").attr('tabindex', "-1");
    $("h1:visible").css('background-color', '#aaa');
    $("h1:visible").focus();
  });

  // For changing between all jQuery Mobile pages. https://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#event-change
  $(document).on('pagecontainerchange', function() {
    console.warn('New cool event, that always triggers, Pagecontainerchange on document, Sano.');
    $("h1:visible").attr('tabindex', "-1");
    $("h1:visible").css('color', '#dd4814');
    $("h1:visible").focus();
  });

})();
```

Triggering from an event (https://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#event-change ), promise, or callback is better than using a timed wait, so that can avoid not having to guess how long rendering your display changes will take.

*Sano* mentioned specifically that https://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#event-beforeshow was helpful.

```
  //for jQuery until  1.4.0
  $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', function() {
    $(".ui-page-active > .ui-header h1").attr('tabindex', "-1");
    $(".ui-page-active > .ui-header h1").focus();
  });
  //for jQuery 1.6.0+ (Also works for 1.4)
  $(document).on('pagecontainerbeforeshow', function() {
    $(".ui-page-active > .ui-header h1").attr('tabindex', "-1");
    $(".ui-page-active > .ui-header h1").focus();
  });
```

Comment: as mentioned in my code .focus() .click() etc etc not working

Comment: also your code has an error should be $(".ui-page-active .ui-title").focus() because h1:visible will select all h1 elements in the visibile page

Comment: You did not provide the html you are using, that is why it is hard to help you. I told you in my answer, I am not setting focus on a nav-item, but on the an h1(in most cases you *should* only be one  h1 on a page at a time) below the header, in the body. I will update my answer to make this more visible.

Comment: Also, when you say, not working, do you mean even doing an `$(".nav-item .page1").click(function() {alert("Hi Sano!");});` doesn't work?

Comment: @Sano added a working example in my answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: Eric first of all when i say "not working" i mean that the VoiceOver after $.mobile.changePage("page1.html"); don't focus on the title. Your code is working with normal browsers not with voiceover. In my oppinion your code isnt relate with the problem i am trying to solve, maybe my first post isnt clear

Comment: Eric, did you test your code with voiceover activated?

Comment: @Sano, I tested it on an iPad mini with iOS 9.3.1 with VoiceOver on. It worked as expected, reading You need do both **Run code snippet** and click **Full Page** (for some reason VoiceOver acts strangely with embedded iframes). I'll list the steps I used in the answer.

Comment: Eric, https://jsfiddle.net/218xLbwd/14/ this is a test page, if yu try play with it many times, not always focus works like expect. VoiceOver behavior on webpages with safari is litle different than VoiceOver on MobileWebApp

Comment: @Sano https://jsfiddle.net/EricOP/wo40z1m9/ is an updated version. In JS, if you can not use the, "wait 1000 ms while the view updates and hope it's long enough", you want to. Instead you want to trigger off a callback or an event. In my example I trigger off the event http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagechange/ for example

Comment: Eric the solution is in beforeshow event. Thanks for you advices. I think is good if you update your solution with less code to make it more clean

Comment: @Sano good team work. Glad we solved it! Tried to cut my answer in half, and remove the early stuff so you could upvote and approve it in good conscience.